# Where can I find a .net library to work with openldap?

Tags: .net, asp.net, openldap

I have to work with an openldap server, where can I find a .net libary to work with that protocol?

I would even settle for some code to work with openldap, I've search high and low online and can't find anything specific to .net. I just need to add a user and set their password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I've used the built in .net libraries for querying an ldap server. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989051/how-to-extract-tnsnames-from-an-ldap-directory) for an example of the code (in F#, but using the standard .Net libraries). It uses System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

Comment: I agree that starting with the built-in System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.Protocols is the best place to start. It might be good to point out you are using F# (I'm pretty sure its F# anyway) so he doesn't look at it and think oh god what is that.